# Visual Studio. already defined in ....obj

Tags: visual-studio-code

Пробовал организовать проект по правилам, объявляя классы .h , и определяя их в .cpp. Вроде все правильно, файлы .h вызываю один раз, но все время эта ошибка "already defined in ....obj".
Сделал абсолютно примитивный проект, с одним .cpp и .h (чтоб не учиться на проектах с десятками файлов), но и тут тоже самое "already defined in ....obj".

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include "Source.h"

    int main()
    {
        std::cout << &a;
    }








//...Source.h
class oneee {


    int strdr();
}a;





   //...Source.cpp 

    #include "Source.h"
    int oneee::strdr() {

        return 299;
    }
```

*В чем проблема?
если делать реализацию прямо в .h то все норм.*

Ошибка LNK1169: обнаружен один или несколько кратно определенных символов DeclareImplement D: \ MyVisualStudioProg \ DeclareImplement \ Debug \ DeclareImplement.exe 1

Если сделать так(все вставить в Source.h), то все хорошо:

```
//......Source.h
    class oneee {


        int strdr();
    }a;


    int oneee::strdr() {

        return 299;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что #include это препроцессор, который по факту просто вставляет содержимое заданного файла(можно даже *.txt вставить) и получается компилятору по факту отдается:

Source.h

```
class oneee {
    int strdr();
} a;
```

Source.cpp

```
    class oneee {


    int strdr();
} a;

int oneee::strdr() {

    return 299;
}
```

Получается что когда скомпилирован cpp в obj там уже есть определение "a". И при подключении Source.h основной файл оно дублируется.

Исправить это можно добавив static в .h

```
 static class oneee {
        int strdr();
    } a;
```

Но это создаст по копии переменной в каждом исходнике так что лучшим способом будет:

Source.h

```
extern class oneee {
            int strdr();
        } a;
```

Source.cpp

```
    #include <Source.h>
     int oneee::strdr() {

            return 299;
        }

oneee a;
```